# Testing google analytics integration in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4, google-analytics

I have successfully uploaded my app in iTunes store. Now, I want to include Google Analytics in my app.

I have integrated the Google Analytics framework and have written the code for required functionality. Now I want to test if Google Analytics integration works correctly, before releasing updated app to Appstore.

How can I test Google Analytics functionality?

Comment: just use your app and log into the google analytics web to check if it's working

Comment: Go to your analytics dashboard and see if the data are correctly sent.

Comment: For using the app into google analytics we should have it in live or not..?

Comment: Can we able to check it before we upload the app into iTunes store?

Comment: @SURESHSANKE. I have same question. should the app be live for testing ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this tutorial [Google Analytics - Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios/)
This will help you to setup all you need for development.